# $a < {\sqrt 3}b$ with certain conditions

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Given two integers $a > b > 1$ such that $(a+b)|(ab+1)$ and $(a-b)|(ab-1)$. Prove that $a <$ $\sqrt 3$$b$. My approach was to firstly look for some inequalities but I couldn't come up with any useful. Then I tried to plug some numbers and I found out that if $a$ and $b$ differ by $2$ and both are $odd$ the conditions are satisfied, then I tried to look for some other $a$,$b$ that differ by $2n$ but I couldn't find any. So I think that it is the case in this problem, but I can't proceed. Any hints and was my approach correct so far? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, we conclude that $a+b\mid ab+1\implies $gcd$(a,b)=1$. Also, observe that $$a+b\mid b\cdot (a+b)-(ab+1)=b^2-1\qquad \text{and} \qquad a-b\mid (ab-1)-b\cdot (a-b)=b^2-1$$ Besides, notice that, since gcd$(a,b)=1$, we also have gcd$(a+b, a-b)=\text{gcd}(2a, 2b)=1$ or $2$. This yields $$(a+b)(a-b)\mid 2\cdot (b^2-1)\implies a^2-b^2\leqslant 2(b^2-1)<2b^2\implies a<\sqrt3 b$$